# Freeze Row 10 to Column D

Tags: excel

I know the function in Excel to either freeze rows or columns. I'm trying to create a blok that freezes when you scroll down.

Example: I have a large list of data that the user needs to fill in. Additional I have a checklist which I want to be able to show if the user needs it. Preferably I want to have the function to hide/ unhide columns A to D (I already have the macro), and have the checklist in this field. If I however scroll down, the checklist doesn't stay in place. The only option now is to freeze all 10 rows, but then the viewing field is small.

Is there a way to freeze of block cells A1 to D10. That if i scroll down the A1 to D10 stay frozen, but not have to freeze all the rows to 10.

Note: I need the checklist to interact with the datasheet, so placing an image won't work unfortunately.

Comment: No. You can't freeze part of a row.

Comment: Oke, thanks for the reply BigBen.